# Swift 3 Realm Crashes with IOS 10 Simulaor

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I have recently upgraded an app that includes Realm Swift to Swift 3. I have also upgraded the Realm pod to the latest version that supports Swift 3.

With Swift 2.2 all was good
I can build the app fine.

when I run the app in the simulator it crashes when I carry out my first Realm command with the following debug error

```
2016-10-31 21:53:59.652525 # MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.654172 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.655775 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.657456 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.661452 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.667299 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.671652 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.675755 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.680503 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.687101 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.691908 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-10-31 21:53:59.703852 MyAppName[3772:306703] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24,
```

any thoughts on how I go about troubleshooting or fixing this issue?

Comment: They are not crash log and not related Realm. Those logs are printed when network access (e.g. using `URLSession`) from Xcode 8 (maybe Xcode's bug). Is the app actually crashed? If so, can you try to comment out initializing Realm for isolate the problem?

Comment: The investigation I had done is to put breakpoints in the code in and around the Realm initialization. I get the output only when I call the Realm initializer code.

Comment: So it's not a crash, right? If so, it's intended behavior. Realm collects anonymous information when running on simulators. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMAnalytics.mm#L236 So when initializing Realm, a network access is occurred. That's why the logs are shown.

Comment: Hey Kishikawa, yeah it just seems that the latest version of Xcode is VERY chatty is providing a lot of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Kishiwaka it seems these are normal outputs from Xcode and as I commented it seems that Xcode 8.1 has suddenly become very chatty and is giving more 'informational' output rather than just errors and print statements.

Comment: To disable this, go edit your scheme and under the Arguments tab include an environment variable for OS_ACTIVITY_MODE and set it to disable. Xcode won't be 'so' chatty anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Was experiencing the same thing with Crashlytics. After clearing the Derived Data, everything worked fine.

To get to the Derived Data:

1. Xcode > Preferences...
2. Locations (tab)
3. (Double) Click on the circle (with right arrow inside it) on the Derived Data row.
4. DerivedData is shown. Delete its content.